# Find changesets based on workitem ID linked

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, tfvc

I'm looking for an API endpoint which can result me into the Changesets associated with the workItemID I provide as body of the API.

i.e. if I give workitemID as 12, it should return all the Changesets associated/linked with that workItem.

My project is in Azure DevOps and using TFVC.

Comment: I didn't find any existing questions helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) Rest Api with `expand` parameter. Then you can find `ArtifactLink` that started with `vstfs:///VersionControl/Changeset/` URL. Powershell example:

```
$user = ""
$token = "<YOUR PAT>"
$teamProject = "<YOUR PROJECT>"
$orgUrl = "<YOUR ORG URL>"
$chUrlTemplate = "vstfs:///VersionControl/Changeset/"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uriGetWI = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/wit/workitems/2155?api-version=6.0&`$expand=all" #update id here (2155)

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriGetWI -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}    

foreach ($rel in $result.relations)
{
    if ($rel.rel -eq "ArtifactLink" -and $rel.url.StartsWith($chUrlTemplate))
    {
        $changeSetId = $rel.url.Replace($chUrlTemplate, "");

        Write-Host "ChangeSet Id:" $changeSetId
    }
}
```